# How default height and width for Flutter GridView children is calculated?

Tags: flutter, gridview, dart, flutter-layout

Implementing gridview in flutter is so easy that it can be done with less than 30 lines of code as explained in the below link.

[Flutter Gridview sample](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/lists/grid-lists)

When running the above snippet generates the grid view as expected. We are not providing any height / width param and also aspect ratio is not mentioned for the grid children.

> **I'm wondering how the height and width of the grid tile is calculated.**
>
> Does this have any default aspect ratio ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is the description for the example in the GridView documentation:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html

Container widgets are filling the available space since their height and width properties are not specified. GridView.count padding is set to 20, so there is 20 px space outside containers. GridView.count crossAxisSpacing and mainAxisSpacing are set to 10, so there are 10 px spaces between containers. GridView.count has also AspectRatio property and it is 1.0 by default, so container height and width is equal making it square. Each container padding is set to 8, so text in each container is 8 px away from container edges.

```
GridView.count(
  primary: false,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
  crossAxisSpacing: 10,
  mainAxisSpacing: 10,
  crossAxisCount: 2,
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: const Text('He\'d have you all unravel at the'),
      color: Colors.teal[100],
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: const Text('Heed not the rabble'),
      color: Colors.teal[200],
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: const Text('Sound of screams but the'),
      color: Colors.teal[300],
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: const Text('Who scream'),
      color: Colors.teal[400],
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: const Text('Revolution is coming...'),
      color: Colors.teal[500],
    ),
    Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: const Text('Revolution, they...'),
      color: Colors.teal[600],
    ),
  ],
)
```

In the example in your link, there are center widgets adjacent to each other and there are text widgets inside them. Since AspectRatio is 1.0, height and width is both equal to half of screen width. It is more simple than the example in the documentation.